How should I direct water away from my foundation and doorway? (Brick patio on concrete slab)
I have a brick patio laid on top of a concrete slab with a generous slope toward my foundation and garage entrance. Water routinely makes its way under the door in the garage, and during heavy rain I will get a little water in the corner of my basement.
How should I direct water away from my foundation/door in this situation?
And should I attempt to fill the gap between the foundation and the slab to prevent water along the foundation?




Is the slab original, or was it part of the patio construction?

The slab is original and the brick patio was overlayed on top.

Did the OG patio have drainage issues?

I believe so yes.

The proper solution would be to redo (part of) the patio and make sure it slopes away from the house.
If that's not an option you can add a channel drain along the wall to catch the water and divert it to where it can be dealt with.
Once you have that solution to manage water you shouldn't need to do anything extra to deal with the water.

I think it would be tough to redo the concrete because the brick comes right up to the bottom of the door, so I would have to deal with the door, siding, and a window that is not shown in the pic.
If I were to add a channel drain, would I put it level with the top of the brick?

The top of the channel drain will need to be level with the top of the brick.
